# What can I do when apt-get/aptitude doesn't create a menu item for an installed program?

Tags: gnome, debian, desktop-environment, menu

Obviously, this question is specific to Debian-based setups.

I find that, often, packages I install using aptitude or apt-get only *say* that a menu item has been created. No menu item actually appears. Obviously, I can create one myself, but that requires knowing what the binary was actually called (in many cases different from the package name). There must be a simple way to know which directories things have been installed in.

So,

1. Does anyone know why the creation of menu entries fails?
2. How can I get info about where the binaries reside/what they're called, in order to create my own menu entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see a message telling you that a menu entry has been created, it means the package has dropped a file into `/usr/share/menu` describing one or more menu entry, as per the [Debian menu policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/menu-policy/). The [documentation of the menu system](https://alioth.debian.org/docman/view.php/30046/2/menu-one-file.html) (also available in `/usr/share/doc/menu`) explains the syntax of this file. Each window manager is supposed to include the system menu. Gnome doesn't do the standard thing, though (so what else is new).

Gnome and KDE show a menu constructed from entries in `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` and `/usr/share/applnk/**/*.desktop`, following the [Freedesktop menu specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/). Not all packages provide those. You can create a `.desktop` file based on the Debian entries and put it in `~/.config/menus/`.

Comment: You can configure GNOME/KDE to add a 'Debian' sub-menu to their menus.

Asides from that, policy says "All packages that provide applications that need not be passed any special command line arguments for normal operation should register a menu entry for those applications" -- so any that don't, should have a bug filed against them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
dpkg -L package-name-goes-here
```

...to have a list of files that have been installed by the specific package. If you just want executable files:

```
for file in `dpkg -L package-name-goes-here`
do
  if [ -x $file -a ! -d $file ] # must be executable, but not a directory.
  then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Here's [a naively, hastily written script](https://gist.github.com/708848) that does the above. Usage: `exec-files-from-package [package]`.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way than this :)

Comment: @ixtmixilix I shouldn't be saying this, but it is quite unfair if you say "Thank you, this works for me" without upvoting, please see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/263/250

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to find the binaries: `dpkg -L $pkg |grep bin/`.

Comment: not bad, but misses the edge-case `/usr/games`.